# .Net ComboBox Binding Issue

Tags: .net, combobox, sorting, selectedvalue

I have 2 comboboxes, each are bound to the the same DataTable like so:

```
    channelTypeCB.DataSource = SynergyData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"];
    channelTypeCB.DisplayMember = "channelType";
    channelTypeCB.ValueMember = "channelTypeID";
    channelTypeCB.BindingContext = new BindingContext();

    newSKChanTypeCB.DataSource = SynergyData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"];
    newSKChanTypeCB.DisplayMember = "channelType";
    newSKChanTypeCB.ValueMember = "channelTypeID";
    newSKChanTypeCB.BindingContext = new BindingContext();
```

When I click a button to insert a record into the database, I use channelType.SelectedValue... which is returning the incorrect value. I have a feeling it has something to do with using the ComboBox sort (which I set in the properties of the control in the design view). Has anyone ran into this problem?

This is programmed for a winforms application using C#

Edit:

For example, my Datatable stores values like:

> ```
> channelType    channelTypeID
> Web             2
> Mailer          3
> Catalog         4
> ```

This is sorted in the combobox, and when I select the first item (which would be "Catalog" when sorted) the SelectedValue returns 2, when I select the second item it returns 3.... I would have expected "Catalog" to return 4

Comment: What do you mean when you say "returning the incorrect value"?

Comment: For example, I select one item in the combobox and channelType.SelectedValue is definately not returning the correct one... This inserts data into my database, and its putting them in the wrong category (i triple checks the numbers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MSDN [ComboBox.Sorted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted.aspx)

Probably related to this

> Attempting to set the Sorted property
>   on a data-bound control raises an
>   ArgumentException. You must sort the
>   data using the underlying data model.

(Wasn't getting any errors though)

So instead of using the ComboBox.sort, I'm sorting the DefaultView of the DataTable:

```
SynergyData.ds.Tables["ChannelTypes"].DefaultView.Sort = "channelType";
```

Not convinced this is the the best way to go about it, but it works, and now selectedValue returns the correct thing

Answer (score 1):

You may be referring to channelTypeCB.SelectedValue in your code, when you need to be referring to newSKChanTypeCB.SelectedValue (this is a total guess based purely on your control names).

Comment: definately referencing the correct one (channelTypeCB.SelectedValue)... its almost as if the DisplayMember is getting sorted but the ValueMember isnt

Comment: Try commenting out the ".BindingContext = New BindingContext();" lines. Not sure what that's doing, exactly, but it might be removing the normal BindingContext (the one that works) with an empty one that doesn't work.

Comment: IN fact thats exactly what its doing... I would have thought it only sorts on the DisplayMember? ... the ValueMember is sorted seperately?

Comment: I have to create a new BindingContext so that when I change the selectedindex on one combobox, the other combobox doesnt display the same thing  (I saw it done that way in a post by someone at MS)

Comment: @Chris: there's no way a ComboBox should ever sort the DisplayMembers separately from the ValueMembers. Only Excel does things like that.

Comment: @Chris: I think a better way to keep the two ComboBoxes from always displaying the same thing is to bind the second ComboBox to a different DataTable that you Clone() from the first DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this differently: I would create 2 separate `BindingSource`'s, each based on your `DataSet`, and then bind each controls `DataSource` to the respective `BindingSource` just created.

Comment: Just updated my code to use this, didnt fix the selectedIndex problem, but thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in .net

Please upvote this to have it fixed in .net 5:
http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/542353/combobox-selectedvalue-returns-incorrect-data-when-sorted-is-true

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the Sorted property of ComboBox because your data come from a DataTable.

When the Sorted property is used, ComboBox organizes the DisplayMember only and ignores another data as it can not modify the DataTable directly. Example:

Data from DataTable as DataSource without Sorted

```
channelType   channelTypeID  ComboBoxDisplayMember    ComboboxValueMember
Web            2              Web                       2
Mailer         3              Mailer                    3
Catalog        4              Catalog                   4
```

now with Sorted Property

```
channelType   channelTypeID  ComboBoxDisplayMemberSorted   ComboboxValueMember
Web            2              Catalog                       2
Mailer         3              Mailer                        3
Catalog        4              Web                           4
```

This problem can be solved in the database adding at end of query: "ORDER BY FieldName"
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx